# Google Compute Engine Tutorial Not Working

Tags: google-compute-engine

Following, the tutorial on Google Compute Engine, Setting up a VM, I was unable to make the external IPs work.

I created a frontend instance as well as a backend instance.

FrontEndInstanceURL: http://104.196.177.94/ 
[image: FrontEndInstanceURL]

BackEndInstanceURL: http://104.196.223.176/ - Unable to connect to page

Answer (score 0):

it seems mongodb listens on port `:80`, use `:27017` instead.

add firewall rules for the ports you intend to connect; eg. `:1000`.

with two screenshots, this is not anything one could understand.

Comment: Accesing the IP address you've provided from a browser throws this message [1] you can SSH or RDP into the GCE instance and make sure that the services you run there are on the correct port.


[1] You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Comment: @Paula, how do I add the ports? The tutorial does not show how to add ports.

Comment: I'm not sure that you've understood what I've said.

My approach here is that you SSH/RDP into the GCE instance and make sure that the services you run there are on the correct port, and then troubleshoot based on that information.

You can run netstat -tulpn once you've logged into the instance to check connections and ports in use in the instance.
Here you have the man page for netstat in case you need it: 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html